# Have different apps with same signature and sharedUserId?

Tags: termux

I'd like to use the official port of Emacs for Android along with the packages provided by Termux.

This is what the Emacs manual says:

> ## H.9 Installing Extra Software on Android
>
> An exceptionally limited set of Unix-like command line tools is
> distributed alongside default installations of Android. Several
> projects exist to augment this selection, providing options that range
> from improved reproductions of Unix command-line utilities to package
> repositories providing extensive collections of free GNU and Unix
> software.
>
> Busybox (http://busybox.net) provides Unix utilities and limited
> replicas of certain popular GNU programs such as ‘wget’ in a single
> statically-linked Linux binary, which is capable of running under
> Android.
>
> Termux (https://termux.dev) provides a package manager based on the
> Debian project’s ‘dpkg’ system and a set of package repositories
> containing substantial amounts of free software for Unix systems,
> including compilers, debuggers, and runtimes for languages such as C,
> C++, Java, Python and Common Lisp. These packages are customarily
> installed from within a purpose-built terminal emulator application,
> but access is also granted to Emacs when it is built with the same
> application signing key, and its “shared user ID” is set to the same
> package name, as that of the terminal emulator program. The file
> ‘java/INSTALL’ within the Emacs distribution illustrates how to build
> Emacs in this fashion.
>
> termux-packages (https://github.com/termux/termux-packages) provides
> the package definitions used by Termux to generate their package
> repositories, which may also be independently compiled for
> installation within Emacs’s home directory.
>
> In addition to the projects mentioned above, statically linked
> binaries for most Linux kernel-based systems can also be run on
> Android.

I'd like to use the method #2 (Termux, not `termux-packages`) since it allows me to have a shared set of installed packages for both Emacs and Termux. Luckily, the mantainer of this port regularly releases the compiled Emacs apk and even took care of providing a custom signed .apk of Termux on its [SourceForge page](https://sourceforge.net/projects/android-ports-for-gnu-emacs/) (Look at the README for more details).

However, no `Termux-API` or other related app is given, which means that if I ever need them I'll need to compile all the apps (Emacs, Termux, Termux-API, etc.) with my own signature. Is there a way to prevent this or, at least, make it so that I don't have to compile Emacs (which is the hardest to build)?

Comment: What do you mean by `Termux-API`?

Comment: @Robert https://github.com/termux/termux-api Termux add-on app which exposes device functionality as API to command line programs.

Comment: Are you aware that you can resign apps (APKs) to make them have the same signature. No need to rebuild the apps from scratch. Just try to sign all your APK files using `apksigner` from Android SDK using the same key (I am not sure, may be you have to unzip the APK and re-build the APK ZIP file before resigning).

Comment: @Robert i was not aware of that.